# same data members in both base and derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance

I am new to C++ programming, i am reading inheritance concept, i have a doubt about inheritance concept which is: what will happen if the base and derived class have same data members. And also please go through my code as below:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class ClassA
{
   protected :
       int width, height;
   public :
       void set_values(int x, int y)
       {
           width = x;
           height = y;
       }
};
class ClassB : public ClassA
{
    int width, height;
    public :
        int area()
        {
            return (width * height);
        }
};

int main()
{
    ClassB Obj;
    Obj.set_values(10, 20);
    cout << Obj.area() << endl;
    return 0;
 }
```

In the above i am declaring data members with the same name as Base class data members, and i called the `set_values()` function with the derived Class Object to initialize the data members `width` and `height`.

When i call the `area()` function, why did it return some garbage value instead of returning the proper value. And it is happening only when i declare data members with same name as base class data members in derived class. If i remove the data members declared in derived class it is working fine. So what is the problem with declaration in derived class? please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `width` and `height` data members in `B` *hide* (or *shadow*) those in `A`.

They serve no useful purpose in this case and should be removed

If you want to access the *hidden* (or *shadowed*) data members, you can use scope resolution:

```
        int area()
        {
          return (A::width * A::height);
        }
```

Comment: okay fine.. but derived class inheriting the set_values() function na then why it is not initializing the data members declared in the derived class.

Comment: Because the base class doesn't know about the members of the derived class. Try removing `width` and `height` from `ClassA` and see what happens.

Comment: okay..if i removed that it will work fine. let us assume there are no data member declarations in derived class, and when i call set_values() function it initialize the base class's width and height members and same will be reflected in area() function but if declare the data members in derived why set_values() function not initializing the derived class data members even though it is inherited by derived class .

Comment: Because the base class doesn't know about the members of the derived class, as @Aesthete said. The derived class has public access to the members of its base class(es) but not the other way around. This is how inheritance works.

Comment: Is this because the members are bound at compile time? If the function was virtual I think it would act on the derived class's members.

Comment: No. Virtual only plays a rule when you access an object via a pointer of a different dynamic type, which is not the case here. Even if you declare both `set_values()` and `area()` as virtual, the result is the same. Virtual or not, there is no way to access `B::width` from `A::set_values`.